# SQL - Query relating to date range from one table and two other tables

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL, starting today at college.

I need to find the telephone number of owners who took their pet for a visit in May 2020.

I have the following tables with the columns and some example data:

```
Visit:
Pet_ID, Vet_Id, Date, Time, Reason, Treatment
P0089 - V04 - 03/05/2020 - 17:50 - Limping - Ointment
P0001 - V04 - 07/05/2020 - 21:00 - Cut on nose and leg - Ointment

Pet:
Pet_ID, Name, Type, Breed, Gender, Born, Owner_ID, Notes
P0001 - Tiddles - Cat - Persian - F - 2009 - 2 - Has a bad temper & Scratches
P0089 - Ginger - Cat - Siamese - F - 2016 - 4 - Bad tempered

Owner:
Owner_ID, Surname, Forename, Title, Tel_Number, Address
1 - Jackson - Janet - Miss - 0141-223321 - 1 Main Street, Glasgow
2 - Singh - Raj - Mr - 0141-326535 - 22, The Hill, Glasgow
```

I have tried the following command.

```
SELECT Owner.Tel_Number
FROM Owner, Pet, Visit
WHERE Visit. Date_ BETWEEN "01/05/2020" AND "31/05/2020" 
AND Visit.Pet_id = Pet.Pet_id
AND Pet.Owner_id = Owner.Owner_id
GROUP BY Owner.Tel_Number
```

But the result shows the telephone number for all owners? What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

EDIT: Apologies, I am using DB Browser for SQLite, not Oracle or anything other system like that. This is for college. And I have added some example data.

Comment: I would suggest sticking with ANSI SQL format as it become more readable. Can you provide table content example where the described behaviour can be seen? Thanks

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

*Always* use proper, explicit, *standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

However, your problem is probably the format of the date strings.  This should always be in standard format.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT o.Tel_Number
FROM Owner o JOIN
     Pet p
     ON p.Owner_id = o.Owner_id JOIN
     Visit v
     ON v.Pet_id = p.Pet_id
WHERE v.Date_ >= '2020-05-01' AND
      v.Date_ < '2020-06-01'
GROUP BY o.Tel_Number
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. Unfortunately the above solution is not working. I have tried '01-05-2020' and '01/05/2020' format as well. There might be something wrong with the tables. Again, thank you for your comment - it is greatly appreciated.